# grabbing a substring while scraping with Python2.6

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, mechanize, substring

Hey can someone help with the following?

I'm trying to scrape a site that has the following information.. I need to pull just the number after the `</strong>` tag..

```
[<li><strong>ISBN-13:</strong> 9780375853401</li>, <li><strong>Pub. Date: </strong> 05/11/2010</li>]
[<li><strong>UPC:</strong> 490355000372</li>, <li><strong>Catalog No:</strong> 15024/25</li>, <li><strong>Label:</strong> CAMERATA</li>]
```

here's a piece of the code I've been using to grab the above data using mechanize and BeautifulSoup. I'm stuck here as it won't let me use the find() function for a list

```
br_results = mechanize.urlopen(br_results)
html = br_results.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
local_links = soup.findAll("a", {"class" : "down-arrow csa"})
upc_code = soup.findAll("ul", {"class" : "bc-meta3"})
for upc in upc_code:
    upc_text = upc.contents.contents
    print upc_text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine `upc_code` is the list you're showing us, and the `local_links` one has nothing to do with your question right?  Given that you don't mention it further in your code...?

So I'm not certain what `upc_text` would be in your loop's body given that `upc` is a `ul` `Tag` -- `upc.contents` is going to be a list of `li` tags (presumably), and I don't see how `upc.contents.contents` can work -- what are you seeing as a result of that code?  I would have expected an exception!

Anyway, the way I'd write the loop would be something like:

```
for upc in upc_code:
    listitems = upc.findAll('li')
    for anitem in listitems:
        print anitem.contents[1]
```

since you appear to want the second child of each list item (the first one is the `strong` tag, the second one the navigable string you want.

If it's not the second child of each list item that you want, please clarify; for example, you *could* identify the strong and get its next sibling, if that suits you better -- just make the body of the nested loop into

```
print anitem.find('strong').nextSibling
```

Comment: you are right, i hadn't changed that when I posted.. the upc.contents.contents didn't work Cheers!